# Using one Drupal views filter, how can I display a child taxonomy where the loaded page represents the parent taxonomy?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-exposed-filter

I've built a portfolio site where the taxonomy structure is basically as follows:

-- Projects

---- Project Category

-------- Project Sub-category

------------ Displayed Project

My site currently has several Project Category landing pages (about 4 right now). From there, I have thumbnails of all of the available projects. Each project is part of any one sub-category within the main project category. I have one exposed views filter within this main view so visitors can isolate a sub category and display the results. The problem is that I haven't been able isolate the sub-categories in that project category page. Right now I can only show all sub-categories vs sub-categories relative to *this* project category page. Does anyone know how to do this via the views panel rather than through a modded php file?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing different view pages for each Project category and adding the needed filter based on what page (parent) you are?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I have considered that but it means creating a larger maintenance arc down the line. Once I pass it off to the client they would have to create a new view once a new project category is created. They won't really know how to do this, not to mention that permissions would prevent a content manager role to get to views in the first place. It must be able to be achieved with just one view, wouldn't you think? I've managed to create all the sections using this one method so I'm really hoping to keep it lean by getting this one filter to play nice.

Comment: then I suggest you use 2 filters, 1 for Project Category and 1 for sub-category

Comment: How would you specifically point to the sub-category? Child levels don't seem to get isolated by the parent page right now.

Comment: Yea you're right .. I did some research and : if u wish to have that "step by step" selection which is available in HIerarchial Select Module ( in D6 ) then i m sorry but i'l have to dissapoint u.. :( we all are waiting for it(in D7)..

Comment: Ah that's such a shame! OK. At least it's good to know that it's really not possible without a php mod on the back end. I'll keep investigating options and keep the thread alive here until a solution is in hand. Thanks Adit!